# Not saving in database table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want edit record in db table but it doesn't save in db table and nothing changed after i submit this form.

Here codes that i forgot to put.

```
<?php
require('db.php');
include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages
$id_doc=$_REQUEST['id_doc'];
$query = "SELECT * from doc where id_doc='".$id_doc."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

This is my php codes

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
    {

        $id_doc=$_REQUEST['id_doc'];
        $query = "SELECT * from doc where id_doc='".$id_doc."'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $title =$_REQUEST['title'];
        $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
        $from_to = $_REQUEST['from_to'];
        $details = $_REQUEST['details'];
        $d_location = $_REQUEST['d_location'];
        $d_stat = $_REQUEST['d_stat'];

        $update="update doc set title='".$title."', date='".$date."', from_to='".$from_to."', details='".$details."', d_location='".$d_location."', d_stat='".$d_stat."' where id_doc='".$id_doc."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update) or die(mysql_error());
        $status = "File Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='v_doc.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
        echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
    }else {
        // here some else code
    }
?>
```

Comment: add closing tag in else

Comment: Don't write data from the user directly to the SQL query. Learn how to use parameters immediately. Otherwise you have a huge security problem on your site.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment.

The issue of parametrised queries aside, I find this easier to read:

```
UPDATE doc 
   SET title = '$title'
     , date = '$date'
     , from_to = '$from_to'
     , details = '$details'
     , d_location = '$d_location'
     , d_stat = '$d_stat' 
 WHERE id_doc = '$id_doc'
```

And now see about parametrised queries

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
    {

        $id_doc=$_REQUEST['id_doc'];
        $query = "SELECT * from doc where id_doc='".$id_doc."'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $title =$_REQUEST['title'];
        $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
        $from_to = $_REQUEST['from_to'];
        $details = $_REQUEST['details'];
        $d_location = $_REQUEST['d_location'];
        $d_stat = $_REQUEST['d_stat'];

        $update="update doc set title='".$title."', date='".$date."', from_to='".$from_to."', details='".$details."', d_location='".$d_location."', d_stat='".$d_stat."' where id_doc='".$id_doc."'";
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $update)) {
          $status = "File Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='v_doc.php'>View Updated Record</a>";            
         } else {
           die(mysqli_error($connection));
         }
        echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
    } else {
        // here some else code
    }
?>
```

This should show you exact error, once you get it. show it here, so we can check and do correction.

Comment: <?php
require('db.php');
include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages
$id_doc=$_REQUEST['id_doc'];
$query = "SELECT * from doc where id_doc='".$id_doc."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

Comment: No need to edit post, comment here what error you are getting

Comment: here i got "Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter" 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());

Comment: Get updated code in original answer. you should pass $connection object always in all mysqli_error function means replace with mysqli_error($connection) at all places

Comment: like this $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error($connection));  sir?

Comment: Just guessing, but it might be the lack of parameterised queries.